# What do the statements at the start of a MysqlDump do?

Tags: mysql

Looking at the output of a mysqldump I see the following at the top.

Similarly scattered throughout I see various statements in /*! */ blocks.  My guess would be that these are probably conditionally executing based on version, but unfortunately with google stripping out symbols it's been difficult to confirm this.

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Here's another reference to these statements in the MySQL manual (that also doesn't explain what they do).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_disable-keys

Comment: Part of the code disables index and foreign key checks so that the database can be insensitive to the order that data are inserted.

Comment: Looks to me like it stores some of the configuration info for the DB (the `@OLD_` parts) and sets them to new values (the ones without the `@`). See, for instance, `SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE` followed by `SET TIME_ZONE`. The `@OLD_SQL_MODE` one both stores the old and sets the new in a single line.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-faq.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice before it creates tables and such you will have a line like this:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

And then after all those things you'll have a line like this:

```
/*!40101 SET @CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

What these lines do is save the database's current settings, change them to what the import file needs, runs the queries, and then sets the database's settings back to the way they were.